# MS Visual Studio 2012 ultimate doesn't start because of MSVCR110.dll

Tags: windows, dll, visual-studio-2012, crt

When I try to run MVS 2012 I always get an error - entry point to procedure _crtCreateSymbolicLinkW was not found in library DLL MSVCR110.dll. I've already copied this dll file from my other computer where everything is working but it didn't help0_o. OS - windows 7.

Comment: This was added in Update 1, used when a program runs on XP.  Bit of DLL Hell going on here with probably an old version of msvcr110.dll.  And the one you copied it from then probably doesn't have Update 1 installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I am going to do a magical reinstallation Update 1 no more

Answer (score 2):

Your best option at this point is to try and repair the Visual Studio Installation

- Control Panel
- Add / Remove Programs
- Select Visual Studio and choose "Repair"

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is missing on the current computer 
download it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679