# VS 2012 Update 3 broke my VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Windows 8 64 bit machine with VS 2012 ultimate. After installing Update 3 and restarting the machine, I get following error whenever I try to open VS.

```
---------------------------
devenv.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The said file is already present in C:\Windows\System32 folder. Please let me know what can be done here..don't want to reinstall that monster again.

Comment: Is your windows a 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 64 bit. Already mentioned in OP.

Comment: Did you...`Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Visual Studio 2012 ultimate doesn't start because of MSVCR110.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623395/ms-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-doesnt-start-because-of-msvcr110-dll)

Comment: You are looking in the wrong directory, it is c:\windows\syswow64 since VS is a 32-bit program.  It probably isn't the only DLL that's missing, also check for msvcr110d.dll and msvcp110.dll for example.  Using the redist is not a fix, you won't get the debugging versions of those DLLs.  Your machine is pretty sick when DLLs go missing like that.  You'll need a doctor, not a programmer.

Comment: Fwiw, forgetting that the installer wanted you to reboot but you canceled that would be a happier explanation.  Reboot before you get drastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check where your projects are being loaded. I have VS installs under both x86 and 64. You'll need downloads for both on a 64 bit operating system.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Please see:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d081943f-fbe8-4a28-b8c0-d83ded9b1a67/msvcr100dll-missing

Some basic tips:

Ensure you have run the install with Administrator rights.

VS won't always ask for a computer restart. However, reboot your computer.

A note about this update.

> Note Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server (TFS) installation
>   mechanics are different. The Visual Studio update installs on top of
>   whatever is already installed on the computer. The TFS update is a
>   full layout that replaces whatever is installed on the computer.
>   Before you try to apply the TFS update, make sure that you have a full
>   backup of your current databases. If the TFS update installation
>   fails, you will be unable to restart the update or roll back to the
>   earlier version of TFS without performing a restore procedure.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600

Comment: Installing both updates solved my problem. However, now when i open VS 2012, it still prompts me to install VS 2012 Update 3.

Comment: That is a new problem and fixed by running the update 3 again and doing a repair this time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error it means you don't have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 3.Try to download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679  .Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a 64bit system, copying the missing file to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder should solve your problem. If it keeps failing for other dll just keep copying.

Comment: Copy the file from C:\Windows\System32 to  C:\Windows\SysWOW64 ?

My C:\Windows\SysWOW64 has msvcr110_clr0400.dll but not msvcr110.dll

Comment: Yes exactly. The SysWOW64 folder can contain 32bit dlls that will be run in the context of a 64bit application

Answer (score 0):

With same error (MSVCR110.dll not found) really reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 not solved all problems. Some VS tools report - not found msvcr110_clr0400.dll. After repair installation of .net 4.0 (or 4.5/4.5.1) all work fine.